# MySQL query to fetch data from multiple tables using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables need the result as shown in below .
need result set where mobile,email and relation will be in same row

There is user table with id(Auto increment) and data 111,112

```
i have tried 

select us.id,t1.mobile,t2.email,t1.relation 
from user us
join Table1 t1
on us.id = t1.pid
left join Table2
on t1.pid = t2.pid

doesn't work as expected.
```

```
    Table1                                                                    
id(AI)          pid         mobile           relation                                 
 1              111         8080808080       self
 2              111         9090909090       mother
 3              111         2525252525       father
 4              112         1111111111       self
 5              112         2222222222       mother
 6              112         3333333333       father


    Table2                                                                  
id(AI    pid    email             relation                                 
 1       111    abc@xyz.com          self
 2       111    cdf@xyz.com          mother
 3       111    htf@xyz.com          father
 4       112    abc112@xyz.com       self
 5       112    cdf112@xyz.com       mother
 6       112    htf112@xyz.com       father
```

need the result like:-

```
 pid            email               mobile           relation                                 
 111         abc@xyz.com          8080808080         self
 111         cdf@xyz.com          9090909090         mother
 111         htf@xyz.com          2525252525         father
 112         abc112@xyz.com       1111111111         self
 112         cdf112@xyz.com       2222222222         mother  
 112         htf112@xyz.com       3333333333         father
```

Comment: This is not query-writing service... what have YOU tried to do?

Comment: Your query have table `user` but your example table only `table1` & `table2`. Post also the result you get from your attempted query.

Comment: There is user table with id(Auto increment) and data 111,112 as i have edited it.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @SandeepModak added the answer as your edited question.

Comment: Please don't just dump wrong code. When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. PS "doesn't work as expected" tells us nothing. Say what you expected & why.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.pid,t1.mobile,t2.email,t2.relation
FROM `table1` as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid and t1.relation = t2.relation
```

Comment: You code should contain a description how it works and solves the OP query/issue? It help to the future readers also.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query

```
SELECT t1.pid, t2.email, t1.mobile, t1.relation 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.pid=t2.pid and t1.relation=t2.relation
```

Try this for your expected result

```
select us.id,t1.mobile,t2.email,t1.relation 
from user us
join Table1 t1
on us.id = t1.pid
left join Table2
on t1.pid = t2.pid and t1.relation=t2.relation
```

add this line on your code

```
and t1.relation=t2.relation
```

Comment: i have tried the same. the problem is there is possibility of same relation like one person can have two SISTER/BROTHERS

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: @SandeepModak , you say _"one person can have two SISTER/BROTHERS"_ but your example data doesn't include that..

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.pid, t2.email,t1.mobile,t1relation FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) carefully to provide a good answer. Your answer lacks some explanation about what this SELECT statement does and how it solves the problem.